# SQL code to remove duplicate rows from same table

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I have the following table with data duplicated for the same test_id. cas_rn 14808-79-8 and 18785-72-3 are the same substance. I need to remove all instances of 14808-79-8 where a row exists for the same test_id but with cas_rn 18785-72-3.

| test_id | cas_rn | Count | result_numeric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 260058 | 14808-79-8 | 1 | 4.0000000000 |
| 260058 | 18785-72-3 | 1 | 4.0000000000 |
| 260062 | 14808-79-8 | 1 | 6.7000000000 |
| 260062 | 18785-72-3 | 1 | 6.7000000000 |
| 260067 | 14808-79-8 | 1 | 79.0000000000 |
| 260067 | 18785-72-3 | 1 | 79.0000000000 |
| 260072 | 14808-79-8 | 1 | 710.0000000000 |
| 260072 | 18785-72-3 | 1 | 710.0000000000 |
| 260077 | 14808-79-8 | 1 | 150.0000000000 |
| 260077 | 18785-72-3 | 1 | 150.0000000000 |

This query shows the rows but I need to add a DELETE statement:

```
SELECT 
    test_id
    ,[cas_rn]
    ,COUNT(test_id) 'Count'
    ,result_numeric
  FROM [dbo].[dt_result]

  WHERE cas_rn IN ('14808-79-8','18785-72-3') AND facility_id = '247561'

  GROUP BY test_id, cas_rn, result_numeric
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Did you try to do `DELETE FROM [dbo].[dt_result] WHERE cas_rn IN ('14808-79-8','18785-72-3') AND facility_id = '247561' GROUP BY test_id, cas_rn, result_numeric` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your query return desired result the deleting is very simple:

```
DELETE  [dbo].[dt_result] 
WHERE test_id IN (SELECT test_id 
                  FROM dbo.dt_result
                  WHERE cas_rn IN ('18785-72-3') AND facility_id = '247561')
```